# Sempre pedir senha no Git Bash Windows

Tags: git, windows

Gostaria de saber se tem jeito de sempre meu Git Bash pedir minha senha no Windows. Não quero que ele grave para nada.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A configuração que você precisa mudar é o `credential.helper`, como você está no Windows ela deve estar como `manager`, você pode conferir executando no console o comando

```
git config --list
```

O Git tem um processo sendo executado que armazena suas credenciais em memória (cache) e dristribui elas sob demanda. Você pode desabilitar o uso da memória de credenciais do Git usando

```
git config --global --unset credential.helper
```

Isso pode não funcionar se estiver definido em um arquivo de configuração alguma configuração que altere toda vez que inicia o sistema que tem essa definição, neste caso uma saída é definir alguma coisa no `config` para `credential.helper`, você pode usar a definição `cache` com o comando

```
git config credential.helper cache
```

Por padrão ele armazena a sua senha por 5 mim, depois volta a pedir, mas você pode configurar para mais ou menos tempo usando o atributo timeout com o tempo em segundos, ex para 2 minutos:

```
git config credential.helper 'cache --timeout=120'
```

Fontes:

https://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials

https://git-scm.com/book/pt-br/v2/Git-Tools-Credential-Storage

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15381198/remove-credentials-from-git

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-credential-cache

Answer (score -2):

Boa tarde,
recomendo que tu passe a fazer tes git command no bash com o HTTPS (**https**://...), pq assim irá sempre te pedir as credenciais.

Comment: Não funcionou com https